# MySQL: преобразовать некорректную дату в корректный формат

Tags: sql, mysql

Какие есть функции позволяющие неправильного формата даты 01-09-2004 преобразовать в корректный формат 2004-09-01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Справка по MySQL

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10.31.2003',GET_FORMAT(DATE,'USA'));
    -> '2003-10-31'
```

Comment: зы. STR_TO_DATE('10.31.2003','%m.%d.%Y');

Comment: Отличная функция.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select STR_TO_DATE(replace('01-09-2004','-','.'), GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR'));
```

Comment: Зачем лишние телодвижения? можно же самому формат составить и убрать лишний replace, и быстрей и красивей.

Comment: Бомбовый пример

Comment: Плохо знаю MySQL. Так и пытался, но где-то ошибся. Может буквочки большие ставил: STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2004','%D-%M-%Y'), но получил NULL в ответе. Оттого и реплейс.

Comment: угу) буквы тут очень важны, регистр в том числе. функции даты хорошо документированы, с понятными примерами))) кстати функция та что у меня прям из доков и выдрана, а в коментарие валидный вариант для даты из поста автора вопроса)

Comment: > а в коментарие валидный вариант для даты из поста автора вопроса)

Тогда поменяйте в нем точки на дефисы, или опять реплейс? :-)